# How to define readonly object parameter for function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, readonly, transpiler

Is there any way to enforce an object parameter cannot be changed in typescript, e.g.

```
interface MyType {
   prop1: number
}

function myMethod(param: readonly MyType) {
   // I want TS complain here:
   param.prop1 = 2
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOxLEN) meet your needs or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent any of the object's properties from being modified, you can use the type utility [`Readonly<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype), like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMsjlAPY4CMAXMiAK4C2ARtANzGkU4BMdjVh0IBfQoRgMQCMMHIhkTdKghgAFuQAmAChxwocJnQBKEOJvkAbdAB4M2PAD4AlMiIk9BpgDoylKsgAvMi87MgA9ABUXCSxyAB+iYlcAMJwICDkYMhwAM65wADmCmDkyADkftTlyGwIcAy5KMDZwLk5yFBmmgC0VujclNBg6N7avACsACwADK6R4eIe+oa+PLxByFRhUTFxCUnxqemZ2XkFxcilFVW8NXUNTcgtz+1wnd19INaDeFAjY0ms3mizEhAQ8ly2QAbnBLAwIHR7LgUMF3L9aFsADRcW50Xg4kScQhKFTqLTaWHwiDOThAA)

```ts
interface MyType {
  prop1: number;
  prop2: number;
}

function myMethod(param: Readonly<MyType>) {
  param.prop1 = 2; /*
        ~~~~~
  Cannot assign to 'prop1' because it is a read-only property.(2540) */

  param.prop2 = 1; /*
        ~~~~~
  Cannot assign to 'prop2' because it is a read-only property.(2540) */
}
```

---

But if you only want to prevent specific properties from being modified, you can mark them as read-only using the [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) modifier:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMslBHACYD2IANusjlFTgIwBcyIArgLYBG0ANzFGzHACZOPAcMIBfQoRjcQCMMBrJe6VBDAALKhQAUOOFDi9OGbHgCUyIiXOXeAOiYtWyALzIJIWQAegAqURJI5AA-WNjRAGE4EBAqMGQ4AGdM4ABzEGQwKmQAci82EuRBBDhuTJRgdOBMjNJyCgBaGnoxFmgwdHcTCQBWABYABkdQ4KUXCytPcQk-ZFYg4ODkKgBrBSUEGkz0gDc4Wm4IGyxcFH9nXrZOVgAaUXKpALf5EUIdPUMxhMZwuEHsIiAA)

```ts
interface MyType {
  readonly prop1: number;
  prop2: number;
}

function myMethod(param: MyType) {
  param.prop1 = 2; /*
        ~~~~~
  Cannot assign to 'prop1' because it is a read-only property.(2540) */

  param.prop2 = 1; // ok
}
```

Comment: I still can pass readonly param as non-reaonly param to another function, any way to prevent it?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74766152/how-to-define-readonly-object-parameter-for-function-in-typescript/74766307?noredirect=1#comment131953307_74766307) @mehran That's a separate question. If you don't find it after searching, you can [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you do, be sure to include a [mre], ideally with a link to the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/Q) with your code that demonstrates your issue.